# Why does the output is just 1 in the table of database?

Tags: php, laravel

So i got the done with previous trouble, now i have a new one, when the function is running, foreach is just loop 1 time. In my table i have more then 1000++ data

Dtraining's model

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Dtraining extends Model
{
    //
    protected $table = 'dtraining';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id_dtraining';
}
```

Knn1's model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Knn1 extends Model
{
    //
    protected $table = 'p_knn_1';
}
```

The function in my controller

```
public function check(Request $request){
        $link = $request -> link;
        $having_ip_address      = $this -> having_ip_address($link);
        $url_length             = $this -> url_length($link);
        $ssl_final              = $this -> ssl_final($link);
        $age_of_domain          = $this -> age_of_domain($link);
        $url_of_anchor          = $this -> url_of_anchor($link);
        $server_form_handle     = $this -> server_form_handle($link);
        $request_url            = $this -> request_url($link);
        $web_traffic            = $this -> web_traffic($link);
        $popWindow              = 1;

        foreach(Dtraining::all() as $tr){
            $v1 = $tr['SFH'] - $server_form_handle;
            $v2 = $tr['popUpWindow'] - $popWindow;
            $v3 = $tr['SSLFinal_State'] - $ssl_final;
            $v4 = $tr['Request_URL'] - $request_url;
            $v5 = $tr['URL_of_Anchor'] - $url_of_anchor;
            $v6 = $tr['web_traffic'] - $web_traffic;
            $v7 = $tr['URL_Length'] - $url_length;
            $v8 = $tr['age_of_domain'] - $age_of_domain;
            $v9 = $tr['having_Ip_Address'] - $having_ip_address;

            $pangkat = pow($v1,2) + pow($v2,2) + pow($v3,2) + pow($v4,2) + pow($v5,2) + pow($v6,2) + pow($v7,2) + pow($v8,2) + pow($v9,2);

            $akar = sqrt($pangkat);

            $tempo1 = new Knn1;
            $tempo1->result = $akar;
            $tempo1->save();
            return redirect('/');
        }
    }
```

And the output is just one where it's suppose to be 1000++ output 
Did i miss something ?

Comment: Please share more details. What do you mean by "1000++ output"? What have you tried to debug the problem?

Answer (score 1):

You put  `return redirect('/');` inside `foreach` loop, In your case, you must put your `return` **outside** looping

```
public function check(Request $request) {
    $link = $request -> link;
    $having_ip_address      = $this -> having_ip_address($link);
    $url_length             = $this -> url_length($link);
    $ssl_final              = $this -> ssl_final($link);
    $age_of_domain          = $this -> age_of_domain($link);
    $url_of_anchor          = $this -> url_of_anchor($link);
    $server_form_handle     = $this -> server_form_handle($link);
    $request_url            = $this -> request_url($link);
    $web_traffic            = $this -> web_traffic($link);
    $popWindow              = 1;

    foreach (Dtraining::all() as $tr) {
        $v1 = $tr['SFH'] - $server_form_handle;
        $v2 = $tr['popUpWindow'] - $popWindow;
        $v3 = $tr['SSLFinal_State'] - $ssl_final;
        $v4 = $tr['Request_URL'] - $request_url;
        $v5 = $tr['URL_of_Anchor'] - $url_of_anchor;
        $v6 = $tr['web_traffic'] - $web_traffic;
        $v7 = $tr['URL_Length'] - $url_length;
        $v8 = $tr['age_of_domain'] - $age_of_domain;
        $v9 = $tr['having_Ip_Address'] - $having_ip_address;

        $pangkat = pow($v1,2) + pow($v2,2) + pow($v3,2) + pow($v4,2) + pow($v5,2) + pow($v6,2) + pow($v7,2) + pow($v8,2) + pow($v9,2);

        $akar = sqrt($pangkat);

        $tempo1 = new Knn1;
        $tempo1->result = $akar;
        $tempo1->save();
    }
    
    return redirect('/');
}
```

Suwun